# Convert incoming mail to plain text

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to convert incoming HTML mail in Outlook to "plain text" and forward the e-mail.

I tried several examples of code.

```vb
Sub ConvertToPlain(MyMail As MailItem)
    Dim strID As String
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
        
    strID = MyMail.EntryID
    Set objMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strID)
    objMail.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
    objMail.Save
     
    Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by plain text? Do you want the raw HTML of the email?

Comment: I want to remove any formatting of the e-mail.  i believe objMail.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain solves this issue, but the code above doesn't work for me.

Comment: What format is the in coming mail. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new mail-item, and set the `.body` property. Reading the `.body` of a mail-item only gets the text, without any formatting (as opposed to reading the `.HTMLBody`, which gets the full HTML).

Here's an example of a sub that'll send the unformatted text of an email to whatever addresses you specify

```
Sub sendPlainText(MyMail As MailItem, sendTo As String)
    Dim newMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set newMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'Create a new email

    With newMail
        .To = sendTo 'Whoever you want to send the new mail item to
        .subject = MyMail.subject 'Copy subject of original email
        .Body = MyMail.Body 'Copy plain text of body to new mail item
        .send 'Send the new email
    End With
End Sub
```